# Regexp newbie stuff

Tags: c++, regex, visual-c++

I want to tokenize from `"[self hello];"` to `"self"` and `"hello"` ... what am I doing wrong ? (MSVC++)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    string s = "[self hello];";
    string x1 = R"raw(\[(\w+)\s+(\w+)\]\;)raw";
    regex re(x1);

    sregex_token_iterator it(s.begin(),s.end(),re,-1);
    sregex_token_iterator reg_end;
    for (; it != reg_end; ++it)
    {
        auto a = *it;
        std::cout << a; // doesn't work. Displays empty string.
     }
}
```

Comment: regex isn't fully implemented in GCC, I heard.

Comment: Not GCC, Visual Studio MSVC++.

Comment: You should really state that clearly in your question because it makes a difference.

Comment: Note: Please take care to make the example [complete](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so we can just run it and tinker (e.g., http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c874396568955b50).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've given the special value -1 to the [iterator constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_token_iterator/regex_token_iterator). This means it should give the unmatched sections. However, your whole string is matched. You can see this have an effect if you make only part of the string match ([live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bd79682957cb81e2)):

```
string s = "abc[self hello];def";
```

Output:

> abc
>   def

Or, you can add text between matches ([live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/43df2921a8734728)):

```
string s = "abc[self hello];def[beep boop];ghi";
```

Output:

> abc
>   def
>   ghi

Here are some other pairs of values and outputs using the same string as the first example:

> 0 or left out: [self hello];
>   1: self
>   2: hello

Comment: In that case I should avoid a for loop and create an interator constructor 2 times, one with value 1 and one in value 2 to get the result, is that right?

Comment: @Michael, You might like something like `std::regex_match`. There's an example [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_match). I believe you could also provide `std::sregex_token_iterator` with a list of indices to use (a la `s.begin(), s.end(), re, {1, 2}`). I've actually barely used any regex in C++ yet, so I don't know what the canonical way to do this is.